# pass method parameter from model to controller

Tags: c#

```
public List<ProductlistModel> GetProductList(int catId)
{
   List<ProductlistModel> products = db.ProductLists.Where(c=>c.CategoryID==catId).Select(s => new ProductlistModel()
}
```

This is my product repository in Business Logic.
I am trying to pass `catId` in controller but it is throwing error.

```
private ProductRepository pr = new ProductRepository();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ProductlistModel> products = pr.GetProductList(catId);
    return View(products);
}
```

How to access `catId` in controller?

Comment: Add `catId` as a parameter to your index method? `index?catId=1`? This is quite easy to do but more information is needed. Maybe find some tutorials on MVC first.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? catId)
{
    // TODO: check catId for null
    List<ProductlistModel> products = pr.GetProductList(catId.Value);
    return View(products);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass catId as parameter. 
You can handle it by passing parameter as string and convert it to *int* before passing to the Function or Procedure of Model